# Short story about a group of people who drank from a chalice and became superior

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A group of people drank from a chalice and became superior. They were being hunted by government, while trying to find and destroy the source of their power to return to normal.  It may have been in *Analog* or *Omni*.

Comment: Are that group of people attempting to return to normal, or is it the government trying to destroy the source?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  In what way did they "become superior?"  Were they faster, stronger, smarter, able to heal, invulnerable, telepathic, etc.?

Comment: Also, welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange!  Be sure to take our [tour] and read over the [FAQ] as well as checking [ask] for suggestions that might help improve your question (and make it easier to find the answer for).

Comment: Definitely echo the Welcome to SFF.SE, walt peifer! "Superior" Like, what… they got elitist attitudes, or became supremacists, or were endowed with holiness, something like that?